# Reading Raw File 1mb at a time, then performing Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to read a file, 1mb at a time, then return data from an regular expression. This is the code I'm using, but I'm not getting anything back and I know these characters exist in the file:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    import re
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    def filemessage(filename, chunk_size=1000000):
        while True:
            data = filename.read(chunk_size)
            if not data: break
            yield data  
            regex = re.compile('abc')
            if regex.findall(data) == True:   
                print (regex)
            else:                   
                continue
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: The `else: continue` branch in this case is redundant and unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall` returns a *list* of matched text.  This will never equal `True` because `list != bool`:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3] == True
False
>>>
```

Simply remove the `== True`:

```
if regex.findall(data):
```

In fact, problems like this are exactly why [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) condemns the practice of doing `== True` or `== False` in if-statement conditions.

---

Note however that you are throwing away the list returned by `re.findall`.  Perhaps you meant to do:

```
if regex.match(data): # Matches from start of string
# or
if regex.search(data): # Matches anywhere in string
```

---

**Edit:**

Your function is running very fast because it is a generator (it yields `data`).  Meaning, Python will not actually run the code inside  `filemessage` until you start exhausting the generator.  So, you are only timing how long it takes to build the generator, not execute it.

You can exhaust the generator with a for-loop:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    import re
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    def filemessage(filename, chunk_size=1000000):
        while True:
            data = filename.read(chunk_size)
            if not data: break
            yield data  
            regex = re.compile('abc')
            if regex.search(data):   
                print (regex)

    for data in filemessage(...):
         # do something with data
```

Comment: It seems to work a bit too quick, like I type the command then it finishes straight away. Is this scanning every mb in the file? Or just the first? If it's just the first, how do I adapt it to scan every mb 1 at a time?

Comment: Well, your `filemessage` function is a generator which yields `data`.  You may just be timing how long it takes to build the generator.  Try exhausting the generator in a for-loop: `for data in filemessage(filename): print(data)`.

Comment: No, I meant put the loop outside the generator to exhaust it.  See my edit.